# Obtain 3D coordinates of an object detected through asus xtion pro live

Tags: opencv, kinect, stereo-3d, asus-xtion

System:
I am using OpenNI 2.2 and openCV 2.4.9 on a Windows 8.1 64 bit machine

I have an asus xtion pro live. This is a RGB and depth sensor that uses primesense technology. I want to use this device to extract the real world 3D coordinates of an object (say a ball) with the sensor's coordinates placed at (0,0,0).
How do I go about it?

Comment: See same for kinect: http://nicolas.burrus.name/index.php/Research/KinectCalibration see first step of "Mapping depth pixels with color pixels" where P3D is computed

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at the [PointCloud Library](http://pointclouds.org/). You will find an `OpenNI Grabber2` at Version 1.7 which has a nice way to work with PointClouds. And here you will find a tutorial for an [`OpenNI 1 Grabber`](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/openni_grabber.php#openni-grabber) which works the same way.